# authenticate Api request to Database by row

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, strapi

Let's say that I have a database Table that stores orders from users.

| Order.id | product | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | user1 |
| 2 | product2 | user1 |
| 3 | product2 | user2 |
| 4 | product1 | user3 |
| 5 | product2 | user3 |
| 6 | product3 | user3 |

And a public API that gives the user all the orders that he requests

I want to prevent user from getting orders of other users and give them access to their orders only.

ie:

user1 can only get order 1,2

user2 can only get order 3

user3 can only get order 4,5,6

How do I do that ? and what is the name of the procedure?

Comment: Like am not fully understanding your question but should the _”WHERE” clause solve this

Comment: Not really the where clause will give access to who ever makes the request through the public api. I want to prevent user from getting orders that are not theirs

Comment: @purplepillow Why would "*the where clause [...] give access to who ever makes the request through the public api*"? Are you building query text on the client side...? Why would you allow your clients to send any arbitrary SQL and get a response?

Comment: If you building the request on the server, I would advise to use a middleware or query the data using req.user

Comment: Yeah, Now that I'm thinking about it i think you guys are right.
I should authenticate the users first and query data server side.

Comment: would you please post your answer so that I can mark this post as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments: SQL queries should **never** be built on the client side in any context. Doing so would present an extremely severe security flaw. Anything that comes from the client should be verified before taking any action on it.

Design your application instead to expose a service that performs authentication/authorization of requests *before* querying the database and returning the data specific to the authenticated user, or data that the authenticated user should have access to.

It may go without saying, but you should also be performing rudimentary validation/sanitization checks *and* using things like parameterized queries/prepared statements in your application to further secure the data within your database from unauthorized access.